# Easiest way to select from 2 tables, with where condition in second

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm selecting all entries from first table which have certain category in second one. Those 2 are connected through ID, which is the same in both tables.

I'm new at UNION and JOIN, so I'm wondering if I can do this without using those? Example:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM entries, 
       categories 
 WHERE entries.id = categories.id 
       AND categories.category = 'default'
```

Comment: Your query is correct, but it's old-style join syntax. You should use ANSI join syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work. You might as well type :

```
SELECT your fields FROM
entries AS E INNER JOIN categories as C USING (id)
WHERE C.category = 'default'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM entries INNER Join categories ON entries.id = categories.id 
  WHERE categories.category = 'default'
```

Comment: There's no reason for a `LEFT JOIN` in this case.

Comment: @Barmar Shall i remove Left Join from my answer

Comment: If there's no matching row in the second table, how can `category = 'default'` be true?

Comment: Isn't that the reason you deleted your first attempt to answer?

Answer (score 0):

The query is correct. Another way:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM entries 
  JOIN catetories ON entries.id = categories.id
 WHERE categories.category = 'default';
```